# What kind of maintenance does a shimano dynamo hub need?

Tags: maintenance, shimano, bearings, dynamo

I have a shimano dynamo hub on the front of my bike.

Does it need any special maintenance, or maybe it needs just a little synthetic grease once a year, like a normal front hub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a Schmidt dynamo hub and it is "maintenance free".  It uses sealed cartridge bearings so there is nothing to grease.  The Shimano hub probably has a similar design?

Comment: As best I can tell, this answer is wrong. At least some models of Shimano Dynamo hubs do have adjustable bearings. See the answers below.

Answer (score 8):

The common Shimano Dynamo hubs don't actually use sealed cartridge bearings, see the [DH-3N71](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/DH/EV-DH-3N71_2N71-2419B_v1_m56577569830621032.pdf) and [DH-3D72](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/DH/EV-DH-3D72-2858A_v1_m56577569830728402.pdf) techdocs. Shimano dynohubs do use good seals, however, and should hopefully be maintenance-free for many thousands of miles.

Alistair Spence has a good [exploded view](http://www.flickr.com/photos/duncancycles/5169065387/) of an Alfine DH-S500, which is very similar to the DH-3D71.  He also links there to a disassembly guide PDF, the original of which can be seen (minus images) in the [internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090107023114/http://trinitybicycles.com/shimanodynohuboverhaul.php).  The steps are basically the same as a standard front hub, with the caveat that it is important to be careful to avoid breaking the axle wire.

Answer (score 2):

The Shimano hub dynamo bearings on one side probably not so difficult and you can look at their drawing but on the other side it can be difficult. I haven't tried to open the other side but you can check this out: http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-700163.html